# C# - How to change attribute of a folder which name is space character (" ")?

Tags: c#, file, attributes

In C#, for changing attribute of folder, I use FileAttributes.
Example:

```
myfolder= "C:\\Test Programs\\Avatar";
DirectoryInfo ss = new DirectoryInfo(myfolder);
ss.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
```

--> Done! Attribute of Avatar is Normal.

But, with some folder which name are " ":

```
myfolder= "C:\\Test Programs\\ ";
```

My program doesn't throw any errors but attribute of that folder isn't change. 
What can i do?

[image]
[Link to fullsize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AyVm.png)

(some viruses created a hidden folder with name is " " and moved all data on usb flash disk into it. I want to remove hidden attribute of that folder)

My English grammar isn't good. Sorry about that!

Comment: what is the attribute you are getting prior to change?

Comment: Did you tried `File.SetAttributes("C:\\Test Programs\\Avatar", FileAttributes.Normal);` ?

Comment: @RanajitChatterjee: that folder is hidden, i want it appear.

Comment: @StriterAlfa: I tried. But i want change attribute of folder whích name is " ", not a folder Avatar. ^_^

Comment: try this             ss.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Normal;

Comment: So try call the folder using single quotes inside the string, something like it: `"'C:\\Test Programs\\ '"`

Comment: @RanajitChatterjee, @StriterAlfa: Thanks for your enthusiasm. I found the answer: added `"\\"` into myfolder. Done! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!. I added `"\\"` into myfolder.
With folder Avatar --> `myfolder= "C:\\Test Programs\\Avatar\\";`

With folder which name is " " --> `myfolder= "C:\\Test Programs\\ \\";`

And my program set Attribute of that folder to Normal.

Thanks every one!.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `+ System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@"&nbsp;") +"\\"` to the end of your directory name instead of the space.

Your string will look like this:
`myfolder= "C:\\Test Programs\\ " + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@"&nbsp;") + "\\";`